# Command-line PHP truncating date("c")

Tags: php, command-line-interface

Here's my PHP code for a shell-script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q 
<?php

$user = get_current_user();
$line = date("c") . " - " . $user + "\r\n";
echo "---------------------\n";
echo "user => $user\n";
echo "---------------------\n";
echo "date('c') => " . date("c") . "\n";
echo "---------------------\n";
echo "date('Ymd') => " . date("Ymd") . "\n";
echo "---------------------\n";
echo "line => $line\n";
echo "---------------------\n";
echo date("c") . " - " . $user + "\n";
echo "---------------------\n";
echo date("c") . $user + "\n";
echo "---------------------\n";
echo date("c") . " - " . "\n";
echo "---------------------\n";

$ret = file_put_contents("/var/lib/foo/bar/test.txt", $line, FILE_APPEND);

echo "file_put_contents => $ret\n";
?>
```

When I run it, I get this output:

```
roffle:/var/lib/foo/bar # php Test.php
---------------------
user => wwwrun
---------------------
date('c') => 2014-07-27T16:39:34-04:00
---------------------
date('Ymd') => 20140727
---------------------
line => 2014
---------------------
2014---------------------
2014---------------------
2014-07-27T16:39:34-04:00 -
---------------------
file_put_contents => 4
roffle:/var/lib/foo/bar #
```

Why is `$line` truncated along with the first two calls to `echo date("c")` and why is the third call to `date("c")` okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've just mixed up + with the . for concatenation in the lines in question.

Comment: Argh! Thanks. The `\r` did some funny stuff too.